# Python function appended values as list values into my dataframe. How to normalize?

Tags: python, pandas

I applied a function to append a list of values to my dataframe using this code:

```
lat=[]
for i in addresses['whole_address']:
    try:
        lat.append([locator.geocode(f'{i}').latitude])
    except: lat.append('na')
        
addresses["latitude"]=lat
```

My output in data frame looks like this and has these [] brackets which are disturbing for more downstream manipulations. How can I normalize these values, so I can calculate distances etc?

```
addresses['latitude']=
              [33.3064318]
11            [33.3064318]
12            [33.3064318]
15     [33.32554963636363]
```

When trying to calculate distances to a given location, I get this error therefore: `must be real number, not list.`

Comment: why are you making `lat` a list and appending to it?

Comment: i didnt find a good way to add directly to my dataframe, so i tried appending it to a list first and then adding it...do you have a better approach?

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way, but as a simple fix, append to value to the list, not a list of the single value: `lat.append(locator.geocode(f'{i}').latitude)`

Comment: @Lroy_12374 I made an answer to show how to do it without a list

Comment: @Lroy_12374, Sorry I misinterpreted what you are doing. I need to adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the apply function.

```
def df_geocode(row):
    try:
        lat = [locator.geocode(f'{row['whole_address']}').latitude]
    except: 
        lat = 'na'
    return lat
        
address["Latitude"] = addresses.apply(df_geocode, axis=1)
```